# Creating a new variable

Tags: r, rstudio

Hi I have a dataset that looks like this

```
bankname    bankid  year    totass  invloc1 invamt1 invloc2 invamt2 invloc3 invamt3   
Bank A  1   1881    244789  Philadelphia    7250.32 New York    20218.20    Philadelphia    29513.4   
Bank B  2   1881    195755  Pittsburgh  10243.60    NA  1851.51 NA  NA   
Bank C  3   1881    107736  New York    13357.80    Wilkes-Barre    17761.20    NA  NA   
Bank D  4   1881    170600  Philadelphia    3.35    Philadelphia    2.00    NA  NA   
Bank E  5   1881    32000000    New York    351266.00   New York    314012.00       NA
```

but I want to create a new variable called `NY_tot` using invloc and invamt variables for each bank. For each bank, if their invloc is New York, then sum invamt. invloc1 and invamt1 go together. Hence,  I want this dataset to look like this.

```
bankname    bankid  year    totass  invloc1 invamt1 invloc2 invamt2 invloc3 invamt3 NY_tot   
Bank A  1   1881    244789  Philadelphia    7250.32 New York    20218.20    Philadelphia    29513.4 20218.20   
Bank B  2   1881    195755  Pittsburgh  10243.60    NA  1851.51 NA  NA  0   
Bank C  3   1881    107736  New York    13357.80    Wilkes-Barre    17761.20    NA  NA  13357.80   
Bank D  4   1881    170600  Philadelphia    3.35    Philadelphia    2.00    NA  NA  0   
Bank E  5   1881    32000000    New York    351266.00   New York    314012.00       NA  665278
```

Here is the dataset I am using

```
bankname <- c("Bank A","Bank B","Bank C","Bank D","Bank E")
bankid <- c( 1, 2,  3,  4,  5)
year<- c( 1881, 1881,   1881,   1881,   1881)
totass  <- c(244789,    195755, 107736, 170600, 32000000)
invloc1 <-c("Philadelphia","Pittsburgh","New York","Philadelphia","New York")
invamt1<-c(7250.32,10243.6,13357.8,3.35,351266)
invloc2<-c("New York","NA","Wilkes-Barre","Philadelphia","New York")
invamt2<-c(20218.2,1851.51,17761.2,2,314012)
invloc3<-c("Philadelphia","NA","NA","NA","")
invamt3<-c(29513.4,NA,NA,NA,NA)
bankdata<-data.frame(bankname, bankid,year,totass, invloc1, invamt1, invloc2, invamt2, invloc3, invamt3)
```

When I tried the following code:

Change factor variables (invloc) to character

```
i <- sapply(bankdata, is.factor)
bankdata[i] <- lapply(bankdata[i], as.character)
```

Then create a new variable

```
for(i in 1:nrow(bankdata)){
 bankdata$NY_tot<-0
for(j in 1:3){
if((!is.na(bankdata[i,paste("invloc",j,sep="")])) && (bankdata[i,paste("invloc",j,sep="")]=="New York")){
  if (!is.na(bankdata[i,paste("invamt",j,sep="")])){
    bankdata$NY_tot[i]<-bankdata$NY_tot[i]+bankdata[i,paste("invamt",j,sep="")]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get 0s in my `NY_tot` variable. Can you tell me why?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because you redefine `bankdata$NY_tot<-0` for every row. You probably want to do this outside the loop.

Comment: You are using `for` loops where you should use vectorisation. This results in slow code.

Comment: How can I do this more efficiently? Can you give me sample codes? Thanks everyone.

Comment: This could probably be solved with ifelse, however, your dataframe is missing the invamt column and I couldn't really figure out what you wanted so i can't provide an answer with the info you have above.

Comment: I believe that for safety reasons, you should use `lapply(bankdata[i], function(x) as.character(x))` instead of `lapply(bankdata[i], as.character)`

Comment: `with(bankdata, { invloc1[in <- invloc1 == "New York"] <- sum(invamt1, invamt2); invloc1[!in] <- NA; invloc1 })` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in comments, you do not need to mess around with for loops to do this. R has a ton of fancy built-in functions to quickly handle problems of this sort.

In this case, your solution is `ifelse`. I'm somewhat confused as to which columns you want to work with, but try something like this:

```
bankdata$NY_tot=ifelse(bankdata$invloc1=="New York",sum(bankdata$invamt1,bankdata$invamt2),NA)
```

What's going on here? `ifelse` works like this:

```
ifelse(conition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

So, in your case the function checks whether the value of `invloc1` is `"New York"`, returns a sum if it is and `NA` if it is not. The nicest part is that it automatically does this row-by-row, so you don't need to manually iterate over the dataframe, which is what is causing problems in your code above.

Edit: as suggested by @Richard Scriven below, you can avoid typing the name of the dataframe four times by using `with` or `within`, eg:

```
bankdata<-within(bankdata, NY_tot=ifelse(invloc1=="New York"),sum(invamt1,invamt2),NA)
```

This is a nifty trick that I will use for the rest of my life, which basically tells R that all variable names given are associated with `bankdata` so you don't have to keep typing it out.

Comment: @Richard Scriven, I've been coding in R for over a year now and never discovered `with/within`... I think you've changed my life.

Comment: And you're also in a different environment.  `a <- "H"; x <- list(a = 1, b = 2); with(x, list(ls(), mget(ls()), get("a", .GlobalEnv)))`.  Pretty neat stuff